# column chart and core chart in one page

Tags: google-visualization

I want to use core chart and column chart both. (reason: i want to use 3D chart as well as pie chart with only percentage).

On First Tab click

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {"callback": chart1,"packages":"columnchart"});
```

On Second Tab click

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {"callback": chart2,"packages":"corechart"});
```

It's working first time.

steps: click first tab then click second tab

When i click again first tab it's loading chart of corechart library

Solution needed

how to load columnchart on first tab click (every time) or how to show only percentage on pie chart(old version).

hoping for solution come out.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dL9uzzbo/

Answer (score 0):

You can only load google libraries once, here is a pseudo code of how to handle it:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {"callback": chartsLoaded,"packages":["columnchart", "corechart"]}); 

function chartsLoaded(){
   tab1.onclick=function(){
       drawChart1();
   }
   tab2.onclick=function(){
       drawChart2()
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for try. but it's not working. here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dL9uzzbo/

Comment: @ANKITTHAKKAR Your fiddle works fine for me, what's the problem?

Comment: Hi, When you are clicking on column chart it's showing core chart. Column chart is in 3D.  here is the fiddle for both graph in column chart http://jsfiddle.net/47gds1yg/

Comment: @ANKITTHAKKAR Unfortuantely 3d for column chart is deprecated, and corechart seems to override older versions. Only way I can think of is to use iframes and put each chart in one iframe, then show the iframe on tab click

Comment: Thanks @juvian for advice but iframe is not suitable. do you have any idea to show only percentage value on tooltip of pie chart(older version,column chart)  jsfiddle.net/47gds1yg

Comment: Old charts are drawn into an iframe, so wouldn't be much difference. And no, old version did not provide this option